# NSMutableArray object property changes its type and value error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, nsmutablearray

my problem is very strange so i can't search for it
i have a model

```
@implementation newChatMessage

@synthesize miDProperty = _miDProperty;
@synthesize mUserName = _mUserName;
@synthesize mUID = _mUID;
@synthesize mPhoto = _mPhoto;
@synthesize mDate = _mDate;
@synthesize mText = _mText;
@synthesize SeenBy = _SeenBy;
@end



@interface newChatMessage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *miDProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mPhoto;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mUID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mUserName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *SeenBy;

@end
```

then i define an object from data coming from fireBase database

```
Allmessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ref = [[FIRDatabase database]reference];
    [[[ref child:@"classes"]child:_classname]observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSEnumerator *children = [snapshot children];

        printf("%s", snapshot.key);
        FIRDataSnapshot *child;
        while (child = [children nextObject]) {
            NSDictionary *obj = (NSDictionary*)child.value;
            newChatMessage* msg = [[newChatMessage alloc]init];
            //NSString *texte = [child ]
            msg.miDProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",child.key];//here its run good
            msg.mText = [obj objectForKey:@"mText"];
            msg.mDate = [obj objectForKey:@"mDate"];
            msg.mPhoto = [obj objectForKey:@"mPhoto"];
            msg.mUID = [obj objectForKey:@"mUID"];
            msg.mUserName = [obj objectForKey:@"mUserName"];
            msg.SeenBy = [obj objectForKey:@"SeenBy"];
            lastOne = child.key;
            [Allmessages addObject:msg];
        }
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        if (lastOne != nil)
            [self lesitner];
    }];
```

this work good and all properties have it's correct value 
but after finishing and start to reload collection view `iDproperty` changes its value and type

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = [super  collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];//here iDproperty type and value changes
    newChatMessage* currentMSG = Allmessages[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.item);
    [[[[[ref child:@"classes"]child:_classname]child:currentMSG.miDProperty]child:@"SeenBy"]setValue:[self senderId]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the value it prints in the error case? You should put that too in question.

Comment: i'm sorry i have found my stupid error it is because i'm define IDproperty as "assign" i have to make it "strong",  but i don't know what i have to do,
delete my question or answer it here

Comment: You can answer and accept if the answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in defining `nsstring` as `assign`
althaugh it have to be `strong`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *miDProperty;
```